# Send Email to Custom Field in Custom Post Type when order is Completed

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

So I have this function that should send the completed order email to a custom email address via a CC.  If the function only contains the if statement (see below) it works correctly. However, when I add other custom code, the email is not triggered.

I have a Custom Post Type that stores the required email address.

The CC email is grabbed from an ACF Post Object field located in the product meta. From that ACF post object field, I grab the custom field (partner_email).

I know that $partnerEmail is valid because I see it logged in the error logs -- however, when I input that variable into the headers, it does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'enyc_order_completed_email_add_cc_bcc', 9999, 3 );

function enyc_order_completed_email_add_cc_bcc( $headers, $email_id, $order ) {

$order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;  

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

$items = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {

    //Get Product ID
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];

    //Get Product Data
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    //Get Partner Data from Product
    $partner = get_field( 'venue', $product_id);

    //Get Partner ID
    $partnerID = $partner->ID;



    //Get Partner Email
    $partnerEmail = get_field( 'partner_email', $partnerID);

    //error_log( $partnerEmail);



}

 if ( 'customer_completed_order' == $email_id ) {
       $headers .= 'Cc: Name <'.$partnerEmail.'>' . '\r\n'; // del if not needed
    $headers .= 'Bcc: Name <dave@eternal.nyc>' . '\r\n'; // del if not needed
    }   


    return $headers;
}
```

Comment: you go from double quotes to single at $headers, There is the mistake

Comment: I tried that, but still no go.

Comment: Okay, maybe this? do you know that in your foreach loop, your variables are overwritten with each loop? so that they are only set from the last item (product) in the last loop?

Comment: yes i see that now, but regardless shouldn't it pass the last product variable which is an email

Comment: Go through your code step by step, rebuild this step by step and test every intermediate step, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

> **How to debug**

**Step 1**

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'enyc_order_completed_email_add_cc_bcc', 10, 3 );
function enyc_order_completed_email_add_cc_bcc( $headers, $email_id, $order ) { 
    // CHANGE EMAIL
    $partnerEmail = 'some@email.com';

    $headers .= 'Cc: Name <'.$partnerEmail.'>' . '\r\n'; // del if not needed
    $headers .= 'Bcc: Name <dave@eternal.nyc>' . '\r\n'; // del if not needed

    return $headers;
}
```

**Step 1 works? -> step 2**

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'enyc_order_completed_email_add_cc_bcc', 10, 3 );
function enyc_order_completed_email_add_cc_bcc( $headers, $email_id, $order ) {
    // CHANGE ID
    $product_id = 100;

    //Get Partner Data from Product
    $partner = get_field( 'venue', $product_id);

    //Get Partner ID
    $partnerID = $partner->ID;

    //Get Partner Email
    $partnerEmail = get_field( 'partner_email', $partnerID);

    $headers .= 'Cc: Name <'.$partnerEmail.'>' . '\r\n'; // del if not needed
    $headers .= 'Bcc: Name <dave@eternal.nyc>' . '\r\n'; // del if not needed

    return $headers;
}
```

**Step 3, etc..**

Comment: yes, i did those processes initally to get the email variable. the only thing that seems to not happen is getting it into the CC field